# How do I resolve this "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" error

Tags: xcode, linker-errors

I have not touched this particular app for some time but have upgraded Xcode in the mean time through various versions up to the current 6.3. Tried to build it today and the build fails with the linker command failed with exit code 1 error...

> duplicate symbol _timer in:
>       /Users/johnbdh2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OrthoPro-cqfociuqwyhagkfczafenrdkthpw/Build/Intermediates/OrthoPro.build/Debug-iphoneos/OrthoPro.build/Objects-normal/armv7/OrthoViewController.o
>       /Users/johnbdh2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OrthoPro-cqfociuqwyhagkfczafenrdkthpw/Build/Intermediates/OrthoPro.build/Debug-iphoneos/OrthoPro.build/Objects-normal/armv7/NewMechanicDialogViewController.o
>
> duplicate symbol _timer in:
>       /Users/johnbdh2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OrthoPro-cqfociuqwyhagkfczafenrdkthpw/Build/Intermediates/OrthoPro.build/Debug-iphoneos/OrthoPro.build/Objects-normal/armv7/OrthoViewController.o
>       /Users/johnbdh2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OrthoPro-cqfociuqwyhagkfczafenrdkthpw/Build/Intermediates/OrthoPro.build/Debug-iphoneos/OrthoPro.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MechanicsViewController.o
>
> ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have found many refs to linker errors both in StackOverflow and elsewhere but so far none have helped me figure out how to fix my particular problem.

The error says that twice I have a *duplicate symbol _timer*, but doing a find in project for _timer doesn't find anything.

I do have NSTimer *timer declared and used in all of the ViewControllers mentioned, but no _timer.

Any help would be apreciated.

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method names have a leading underscore prefix added to them by the compiler so `_timer` in the linker refers to `timer` in your program.

Further the linker message says it is in the file OrthoViewController.o and NewMechanicDialogViewController.o so the variable `timer` is in both of these files with the respective source files *.m and probably at file level.

`timer` is also in  MechanicsViewController.o.

Either make then instance variables or if there is some reason to have them at file scope make them `static`.

If you need more help add the code where the variables `timer` are declared.

It also looks like there may be a conflict between MechanicsViewController.o and NewMechanicDialogViewController.o, perhaps yu only want one of these in your program.

Finally, read the error messages and try to understand them and how they might apply to your code.

Comment: I don't understand why this broke, however. It's not in anyway new and been building and working fine for a long time. It is the first time I had to build and run it since various upgrades of xCode so I am assuming something has changed along the way. Going to try and fix it on my own but may be back for help as I am not sure I understand why 2 view controllers would have a conflict like this.

Comment: I changed 2 of them to static and it successfully builds now. Still do not understand why this was and issue.

Comment: Take a look at what `static` means and in what contexts in the "C" language.

Answer (score 0):

I created this error with this code.

```
protocol var somethingDelegate: class
{
    var position: CGPoint { get set }
}
```

This was a protocol for an SKScene subclass to follow. SKScene already has a position property in it's superclass. I removed this code and it was fixed. The problem therefore may be with duplicate / conflicting properties.